# VectorDrawable Rendering issue on API 23

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am facing problem rendering vector on API 23 and but it works fine on below and above API 23 Android,
I tried different ways to solve it but couldn't do it I was hope if anyone found a way for that.

[image: Android API 24]

[image: Android API 23]

Android API 24 Screenshot: 
Android API 23 Screenshot:

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work on Android 6.0 only ?

Comment: @TGMCians Yes I have tested it on different phones and it works fine on the other version of android 5 and 7.

Comment: `"if anyone found a way for that."`, for what actually?

Comment: @pskink for rendering problem of VectorDrabales in API 23 (Android 6).

Comment: what does `"rendering problem"` mean? vectors are not drawn at all? they are drawn but with different colors? different alphas? different shapes? anything else?

Comment: @pskink shape is getting messed up and not drawing it right

Comment: i am using `VectorDrawable`s on API 23 ant they are not messed up, post your wrong results so that anyone could see it

Comment: @pskink it only ocurs in recyclerview items with image,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149968/discussion-between-anoosh-khalid-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink so now i have uploaded the images of the same recyclerview in different devices.

Comment: @Anoosh Khalid, post xml.

Comment: I am setting the images programmatically by calling setImageResource

Comment: @AnooshKhalid the same vector draws fine when not in a recycler view?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), yourDrawableResId)`